# R accessing a matrix to an array 3d

Tags: r

I would like to access an array 3d with a matrix. Here an example of the desired output:

```
a <- array(1:18, dim=c(3,3,2))
a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   12   15   18
b <- array(1:2, dim=c(3,3))
b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1
 a[b] 
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   13    7
[2,]   11    5   17
[3,]    3   15    9
```

(Should i pass a data frame with 3 columns (indexs + values) instead of a matrix?)

if i do `a[b]`, this is the result:

```
a[b]
 4 11  4
```

and why?

```
c <- array(1:2, dim=c(2,2))
a[c]
[1] 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: If you use a three-column matrix as an index for a 3-dim array, then each row of the index matrix is for one resulting element. So the result you get in your case is identical with `c(a[1, 2, 1], a[2, 1, 2], a[1, 2, 1])`. Your second example is identical with `a[c(1, 2, 1, 2)]`, i.e. indexing with a vector of integers.

Comment: `result <- b;
for (i in 1:nrow(b)) for (j in 1:ncol(b)) result[i,j] <- a[i, j, b[i,j]];
result`

Comment: or `result <- b;
result[] <- a[cbind(as.matrix(expand.grid(i=1:nrow(b), j=1:ncol(b))), c(b))];
result`

Comment: or `result <- b;
result[] <- a[cbind(c(row(b)), c(col(b)), c(b))];
result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for `b <- array(1:2, dim=c(3,3))`

```
> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1
```

the indices are read by rows. Thus, as @jogo mentioned, `a[b]` is actually `c(a[1, 2, 1], a[2, 1, 2], a[1, 2, 1])`

- for `C <- array(1:2, dim=c(2,2))`

```
> C
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
```

since the dimension of `C` does not match `a` (only two out of three fit), in this case `a[C]` is interpreted as `a[c(C)]` (thanks to comments from @jogo).

Comment: @jogo Thanks again! I suddenly realized that I was wrong in my previous explanation. I updated my answer